# Xodus VFS not able to persist bytes

Tags: java, xodus

The problem with the code below is that the VFS does not seem to be able to persist the byte array.
As Xodus VFS writes zero byte:

```
  @Override
  public FileModel put(
      String appId, String namespace, String name, InputStream is) {
    final FileModel[] createdFile = {null};
    final Environment env = manager.getEnvironment(xodusRoot, appId);
    final VirtualFileSystem vfs  = new VirtualFileSystem(env);
    env.executeInTransaction(
        new TransactionalExecutable() {
          @Override
          public void execute(@NotNull final Transaction txn) {
            final File file = vfs.openFile(txn, name, true);;
            try {
              byte[] ba = ByteStreams.toByteArray(is);
              LOG.info("Byte array size: " + ba.length); // Size: 3466
              vfs.writeFile(txn, file).write(ba, 0, ba.length);
            } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }
            long fileSize = vfs.getFileLength(txn, file);
            LOG.info("File Size: " + fileSize); // Size: 0 <----
            createdFile[0] = new FileModel();
            createdFile[0].setDescriptor(file.getDescriptor());
            createdFile[0].setName(name);
            createdFile[0].setCreated(file.getCreated());
            createdFile[0].setModified(file.getLastModified());
          }
        });
    vfs.shutdown();
    return createdFile[0];
  }
```

And here's the log:

```
[qtp1007568224-16] WARN jetbrains.exodus.io.FileDataWriter - Can't open directory channel. Log directory fsync won't be performed.
[qtp1007568224-16] WARN jetbrains.exodus.io.FileDataWriter - Can't open directory channel. Log directory fsync won't be performed.
[qtp1007568224-16] INFO jetbrains.exodus.env.EnvironmentImpl - Exodus environment created: \tmp\xodus\master
[qtp1007568224-16] WARN jetbrains.exodus.io.FileDataWriter - Can't open directory channel. Log directory fsync won't be performed.
[qtp1007568224-16] INFO jetbrains.exodus.env.EnvironmentImpl - Exodus environment created: \tmp\xodus\ab5b92099ad443259b4deaf8df6facc4
[qtp1007568224-16] INFO com.backend.repository.jee.JeeXodusVFSRepository - Byte array size: 3466
[qtp1007568224-16] INFO com.backend.repository.jee.JeeXodusVFSRepository - File Size: 0
[qtp1007568224-16] INFO com.backend.resource.jee.JeeFileServerResource - File size=3466; File.created=1575274836678; File.name="index.html"; File.modified=1575274836678; File.etag=<null>; File.descriptor=261; File.url=<null>
```

Comment: What if you replace `executeInTransaction` by `executeInExclusiveTransaction`?

Comment: @VyacheslavLukianov same result, size of `getFileLength` is zero

Comment: What would be the possible reason that the file size is `0`? Is there a bug in the `writeFile` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `vfs.writeFile(txn, file)` returns an `OutputStream` instance that should be closed to save written data.

Comment: The problem with the VFS also is that when you try to override a file, like `File file = vfs.openFile(txn, name, true);` it appends the stream and corrupts the file.

Comment: It seems if the new bytes to write into the filed is shorter the other bytes that are part of the file still exists.

Comment: And in order to work around this `

`txn -> { vfs.deleteFile(txn, name);
             File file = vfs.openFile(txn, name, true);}` but I feel that this is quite not the correct way to do it.

Comment: It shouldn't append. It doesn't clear the content of the file before writing, it writes above existing content from the beginning

Comment: Ah yes, I mean it writes but does not remove existing bytes, what is the proper way to achieve normal override?